# Split Nested JSON in Java using regular expression

Tags: java, html, json, regex, split

I am new to regex and looking to convert nested JSON into String below are few sample examples below

I need output string like below ,

> 1. {"mainId":"12345","binaries":[{"subId":"123456bd","splitAll":true},{"subId":"123456cd","splitAll":false}]}
>
> Expected output:  12345
>
> [{"subId":"123456bd","splitAll":true},{"subId":"123456cd","splitAll":false}]
>
> 2.{"mainId":"12345","binaries":[{"subId":"","splitAll":true},{"subId":"","splitAll":false}]}
>
> Expected output:
>
> 12345 [{"subId":"","splitAll":true},{"subId":"","splitAll":false}]
>
> 3.{"mainId":"12345","binaries":[]}
>
> Expected output:
>
> 12345 []

How can I achieve this using regex?

Comment: "Requirement is to use regex" : it's either a bad requirement, or a homework. regex is not the right tool for this

Comment: No. No no no no no no no no no. Do not. Please.

Comment: this output will be use as input to testing tool to test test cases , kindly help

Comment: Why can you only use Regex?! it makes no sense to me

Comment: If it is a homework, it's an excellent time to get acquainted with Regex, and it's not that hard to do it anyway, just relax, don't get anxious, get some website that shows you visually what you are doing and use groups with parenthesis, and it should be easy.

Another question is, what happens if you have two consecutive similar blocks.

And again, I cannot stress this enough, WHY REGEX? if you use one of the thousand libraries that parse JSON, it's very easy, why re-re-re-invent the wheel?

Comment: hi its not homework , its requirement of project can't help it.can any regex master help here .i know its sounds stupid but that is what i want.can it be done

Answer (score 0):

Is there a constraint for you to not use a library like [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/)?

Comment: yes , i need to write regex for this .no other library

Comment: its requirement of project , i know it sounds stupid but can't help it. can any expert regex give me regex for this?